# Can't make node move along x-axis in pointofView

Tags: swift, swift-playground, xcode11, swift5

I am working on an ARKit playground project and I just can't get an SCNNode to move along the axis of sceneView.pointofview. When I try with constants like 0.04 etc it adjusts the position properly but when I provide the coordinates relative to the frame of pointOfView I can't get to position it anywhere else but in the centre.
Here is the code for that part:

```
let winglevMain = button(ButtonType: .wing)
    let wingLevButton = winglevMain.button1
    wingLevButton.name = "wing"
    let x = (sceneView.pointOfView?.frame.width)!
    let y = x/2
    let z = x/5
    let total = y+z
    wingLevButton.position = SCNVector3(total, 0.12, -0.5)
    sceneView.pointOfView?.addChildNode(wingLevButton)
```

P.S I used separate constants to store each value because when I tried putting em as it is into the arguments for position, I got an error signifying that it was hard for playground to calculate it that way.